# Perl script which returns multiple exit codes

Tags: perl, jenkins

I have a Perl script that executes another Perl script inside it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case bundling_override);
no warnings 'uninitialized';
#print '<<<check_jenkins_jobs>>>';
my ($port, $host) ;
# Parse command line arguments
GetOptions ('host=s'   => \$host, 'port=s' => \$port);
if( (!defined($host)) || (!defined($port))) {
        print "USAGE:perl $0 -host mbiradar2d -port 8080";
    exit 1;
}
use constant {
    OK => 0,
    WARNING => 1,
    CRITICAL => 2,
    UNKNOWN => 3,
};
my @output = `perl "H:\\Mangesh\\check_jenkins_jobs.pl" -host $host -port $port`;
my $line;
my $status;
my $statustxt;
foreach $line (@output) {
    #print $line;
    my @values = split('~', $line);
    if($values[0] =~ /^CRITICAL/) {
        $status = 2;
        $statustxt = 'CRITICAL';
        print "$values[0] : $values[1] has health score $values[2]";
        exit CRITICAL;
    }
    elsif($values[0] =~ /^WARNING/) {
        $status = 1;
        $statustxt = 'WARNING';
        print "$values[0] : $values[1] has health score $values[2]";
        exit WARNING;
    }
    else {
        $status = 0;
        $statustxt = 'OK';
        print "$values[0] : $values[1] has health score $values[2]";
        exit OK;
    }
}
```

Here is the output of inner Perl script which I am parsing in above script for further use:

```
CRITICAL ~ First_run ~ Build stability: 3 out of the last 4 builds failed. ~ 25
CRITICAL ~ Mangesh_Testing ~ Build stability: All recent builds failed. ~ 0
CRITICAL ~ MKS_Integrity ~ Build stability: All recent builds failed. ~ 0
OK ~ MKS_TEST ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
CRITICAL ~ Rest_api_testing ~  ~ no score
CRITICAL ~ Second_job ~  ~ no score
OK ~ Team_test ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
OK ~ test ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
CRITICAL ~ TEST_1 ~ Build stability: 2 out of the last 3 builds failed. ~ 33
OK ~ Update_Outlook ~ Build stability: No recent builds failed. ~ 100
```

But the problem is this script is exiting after printing the first line of inner Perl scripts output.
I want to exit this script with each output line printed.
What are other ways that I can achieve this?
That would be better if this script exits according to the Nagios compatible output.For eg.0 for OK, 1 for WARNING, 2 for CRITICAL and 3 for UNKNOWN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the script to `exit` after the first line yourself, which each `exit` statement in the `if` blocks.

If you want the logic of your script to stay the same but you want to print everything, let it print the output in a separate loop before processing and exiting.

```
foreach $line (@output)  {
   print $line;
}
```

Comment: Thanks SvenW. I tried that and the script is printing(on console) what I expecting. But I want this output(each line) to be printed on Nagios UI, how could I get over it?

Comment: @Maverick [This is what you're after.](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/pluginapi.html) Please mark SvenW's answer as correct, you are changing the scope of the question from being about Perl to being about Nagios monitors.

Comment: @AndrewB: Thanks, I just was going to look that one up ...